# VB.Net Data (.mdb) content files not available after publish. What am I missing?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-word, publish, mailmerge

I'm writing a program on my laptop that I need to run on my work computer after I publish it. The program does a bunch of database work and then opens a word document and links the mail merge to the data. Everything works fine in debug. It's crashing after being published on both my laptop and desktop.
I've isolated the problem but do not know how to solve it.

It seems the .mdb file, that .docx file wants to read from, is not being copied to the `App_Data` Directory at run-time.  This is weird because I have both the .docx file and the .mdb file in the project as `content` files. The .docx file shows up in that folder and my program opens it just fine.

The only thing different about the .mdb file is that it is also a data source in the project and was brought in by adding the data source instead of just adding the document itself and making the build action `content`. Obviously that's how it has to work, but ... Here's the question finally... How do I get the finished product .mdb file to copy over to the `App_Data` folder so my .docx file can read from it?

Here are the lines of code I'm using now that I thought should work:

```
Dim w As New Word.Application
Try
    Dim Folder As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString
    'MsgBox(Folder)
    Dim Path As String = Folder & "\StandardLetter.docx"
    w.Documents.Open(Path, [ReadOnly]:=True)
    w.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize
    w.Visible = True
    w.Activate()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Couldn't open the document.")
    Exit Sub
End Try
Try
    Dim AccessFolder As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString
    w.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(AccessFolder & "\RenewalTemp.mdb")
    'This does not work after publishing because RenewalTemp.mdb doesn't appear in the AppData Folder
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error accessing the RenewalLetterTemp Database.")
    MsgBox("Path = " & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString & "\RenewalTemp.mdb")
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

EDIT - I've narrowed the problem further but still haven't solved it.  It turns out the problem lies with the directory referenced by this code:

```
Dim AccessFolder As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString
```

That works just fine during debug because it refers to the \bin\debug folder and the .mdb files go there during debug.

At BUILD, they go to a location not referenced by the above code.  I don't know how to reference the location, but there must be a good way.  Also, the directory name contains a bunch of what appear to be randomly generated characters, so I don't know how I would hard-code the location either.  Here are the two directories:

```
Dim AccessFolder As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString
C:\Users\lholk\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\OGMYVLOB.LZH\TD1N8EZX.KAN\rene..tion_7dc5ad3db20d2410_0001.0000_fee3b96b6598cca2

Dim AccessFolder As String = '??? I Don't know what should go here
C:\Users\lholk\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\OGMYVLOB.LZH\TD1N8EZX.KAN\rene...exe_7dc5ad3db20d2410_0001.0000_none_6758ee3059fd9f2f
```

I've looked around in the My.Application space but haven't seen anything else helpful in there.  Can you help?
EDIT 2  - If I refer to the TableAdapter for the .mdb, I can get the following output, which is ALMOST what I need:

```
    Dim Tbl As New RenewalTempDataSetTableAdapters.RenewalLettersTableAdapter
    Dim RightFolder As String = Tbl.Connection.DataSource
'Returns "|Data Directory|\RenewalTemp.mdb"
```

I know that somewhere 'under the hood' there must be a variable that can produce the actual |Data Directory| as it is referred to here between the | | symbols.

Comment: Set `CopyToOutputDirectory` to `CopyAlways`.

Comment: It is already set that way.

Comment: Then it **is** wierd.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to force copy the mdb to a location that I would choose?

Comment: Is it possible something could be broken or missing in the 'under the hood' code that is automatically generated when you link a data source?

Comment: you could save your file as an embedded resource and then on the first load copy it to the exe dir.

Comment: @FarhanAnam I edited in some updated info that I've just discovered.  Can you please take another look?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked to solve the problem.  To clarify, after you publish the program, the data files are stored in a separate location than other content files.  I could not find any thing in the usual classes that would provide this path, so I worked it backwards.
This works in debug mode, after publication, and after updating.  Hopefully it will be useful to someone else as well.

```
        Public Shared Function GetDataFilePath(FileName As String) As String
    'StartPath refers to the location of regular content files
    Dim StartPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString
    If IO.Directory.Exists(StartPath) Then
        For Each file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(StartPath)
            StartPath = file
            Exit For
        Next
    End If
    'DataFolder is where root of where published apps data files go, but the actual directory is 3 levels below.
    'The name of the Folder I'm looking for has the SAME name as the Folder the Content files are in.
    Dim DataFolder As String = Environ("UserProfile") & "\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data"
    Dim Control As String = DataFolder
    Dim DataParent As String = IO.Directory.GetParent(StartPath).ToString
    Dim BackSlash As Integer = DataParent.LastIndexOf("\")
    Dim FolderName As String = Strings.Right(DataParent, Len(DataParent) - BackSlash - 1)
    Dim DataPath As String = ""

    If IO.Directory.Exists(DataParent) Then
        For Each SubFolder1 As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(DataFolder)
            'MsgBox(SubFolder1)
            For Each SubFolder2 As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(SubFolder1)
                'MsgBox(SubFolder2)
                For Each SubFolder3 As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(SubFolder2)
                    'MsgBox(SubFolder3)

                    Dim MatchBackSlash As Integer = SubFolder3.LastIndexOf("\")
                    Dim Match As String = Strings.Right(SubFolder3, Len(SubFolder3) - MatchBackSlash - 1)
                    If Match = FolderName Then
                        DataFolder = SubFolder2 & "\" & Match & "\Data"
                        'MsgBox(DataFolder)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    If DataFolder <> Control Then
        Return DataFolder & "\" & FileName
    End If
    'This makes it so it works in Debug Mode as well, where everything is stored in the bin\debug folder
    Return My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & FileName

End Function
```